# fgets throwing unhandled exception while parsing stl

Tags: c++

I am new to c++, I am trying to parse a stl file which is of about 64MB and has about ~18K lines in it. The code works fine for first few 100 lines but then fgets throws following exception:

`"Unhandled exception at 0x77B0BAC5 (ntdll.dll) in STLparser.exe: 0xC0000024:  There is a mismatch between the type of object required by the requested operation and the type of object that is specified in the request."`

I have checked manually the line for which `fgets` throws exception, there is nothing out of ordinary there. I am out of options for now. Any help to fix this issue will be greatly appreciated.

================CODE==========================

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include"ParseString.h"
#include"Vectors.h"


using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    //Define variables
    FILE *file;
    char *line = new char;
    parsestring oneline;
    int n_Vols = 0, n_Elms = 0, n_nods = -1, E = 0;
    Nod *nodes = new Nod();
    Nod dummy;
    Elm *elements = new Elm();
    int mycounter = 0;
    //Open file
    fopen_s(&file, "sample.stl", "r");
    while (fgets(line, 1024, file) != NULL) //**********Getting Error Here*************
    {
        // populate required data

    }

    fclose(file);
    printf("%d,%d,%d", n_Vols, n_Elms, n_nods);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

===================

When broken, execution resumes at this function (not my function, something internal)

```
void __cdecl _unlock (
        int locknum
        )
{
        /*
         * leave the critical section.
         */
        LeaveCriticalSection( _locktable[locknum].lock );
}
```

Comment: Remember that memory allocated with `new` must be later deallocated with `delete` or `delete []`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
char* line = new char;
```

Do:

```
char[1024] line;
```

You're probably getting corrupted data since you aren't allocating any memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *line = new char;
```

This allocates a single byte on the heap and makes `line` point at it.

```
while (fgets(line, 1024, file) != NULL)
```

This writes up to 1024 bytes to the location pointed at by `line`.  `line` points at only one byte.  This is why your code blows up.

Answer (score 1):

you should allocate necessary memory space for line which will hold your data.

`char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );`

**str**
Pointer to an array of chars where the string read is copied.
**num**
Maximum number of characters to be copied into str (including the terminating null-character).

in your code, you set num to 1024, so your line should point where allocate 1024*char size memory space. So you need modify your code as:

```
char *line = new char[1024];
```

BTW. you should release the heap resource when you do not need anymore.

```
delete nodes;  
delete elements;
```

Answer (score 1):

You call fgets on a single char because you did:

```
char *line = new char;
```

You probably want to allocate a char array of size 1024 instead

```
char line[1024]                // on the stack
char *line = new char[1024];   // or on the heap
```

Answer (score 1):

One issue is this:

```
char *line = new char;
```

You know how big you want to make the array, so there is need to call `new`.  Second, even if you did call `new`, that line above allocates room for just 1 character.

Change the above to this:

```
char line[1024];
```

since again, you know exactly how many chars you want up front, just create an array of that size.

Also, you use `new` in other places where it is not needed:

```
Nod *nodes = new Nod();
Elm *elements = new Elm();
```

Usually these mistakes are made by:

1. Java (or similar langauge) programmers who falsely believe they must create all their objects using `new`, or
2. Beginner C++ programmers who believe they must declare a pointer variable and allocate memory when supplying parameters to a function that has pointer arguments.  Usually all that is required is to pass the address of an existing variable (using the`address-of` operator `&`).

To create objects, this is all that's necessary if the object's lifetime is in the scope of the block it is declared in:

```
 Nod nodes;
 Elm elements;
```

Once you do that then use the `.` operator instead of `->` to access the members of `nodes` and `elements`.

The other issue is that you did not check if the call to `fopen_s` fails with a NULL file handle.  If you call `fgets` with a NULL file handle, then the behavior is undefined (probably a crash).  Always check if you have opened the file successfully before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

You have several correct answers.  However, I think your best approach is to go ahead and write C++:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "ParseString.h"
#include "Vectors.h"

int main()
{
    //Open file
    std::ifstream file("sample.stl");
    if (file.fail()) {
        std::fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open sample.stl\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int n_Vols = 0, n_Elms = 0, n_nods = -1;
    std::string buffer;
    while (std::getline(file, buffer)) {
        // populate required data
        // you can use buffer.c_str() to get a const char*
        parsestring oneline;
        int E = 0, mycounter = 0;

        // based on the name, I suspect you actually want multiple Nod's
        std::vector<Nod> nodes;
        Nod dummy;
        // based on the name, I suspect you actually want multiple Elm's
        std::vector<Elm> elements;
        ...
    }

    printf("%d,%d,%d", n_Vols, n_Elms, n_nods);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Personally, I like `std::`, but others like the `using namespace std` approach you originally used.

I should also mention that `fgets` (and `fgets_s`) doesn't throw C++ exceptions.  There is more than one way to abort your program, and what you're running into can't be fixed by adding a `try { ... } catch` block.

You're probably running into a segfault, but you could be triggering an assertion.  You might even be running into Windows Structured Exception Handling, which, contrary to the name, is different from C++ exceptions.  Your program ends up dying all the same, but it dies for different reasons and you have to do different things to handle exceptions, signals (segfault) or SEH.

Don't worry, you'll eventually learn what those things are; I simply want to point out that "mysteriously dying" **can** be caused by an uncaught exception, but it can be caused by any number of other things.